# How to trigger an existing Argo cronworkflow?

Tags: kubernetes, argo-workflows, argo-events

I have tried many versions of this template below

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Sensor
metadata:
  name: tibco-events-sensor
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        sidecar.istio.io/inject: 'false'
    serviceAccountName: operate-workflow-sa
  dependencies:
    - name: tibco-dep
      eventSourceName: tibco-events-source
      eventName: whatever
  triggers:
    - template:
        name: has-wf-event-trigger
        argoWorkflow:
          group: argoproj.io
          version: v1alpha1
          resource: Workflow
          operation: resubmit
          metadata:
            generateName: has-wf-argo-events-
          source:
            resource:
              apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
              kind: Workflow
              metadata:
                name: has-wf-full-refresh
```

Keep getting errors of workflows not found

```
"rpc err
or: code = NotFound desc = workflows.argoproj.io \"has-wf-full-refresh\" not found"
```

I have hundreds of workflows launched as cronworkflows. And i would like to switch them to be event driven vs cron based. Id prefer not to change already existing flows. I just want to submit or resubmit them.

Comment: Which Kubernetes version did you use and how did you create your cluster? What exactly do you want to achive? What did you try? Please, provide your logs. Those information can be useful with reproduction your problem.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor look down below hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that the argoWorkflow trigger template doesnt support CronWorkflows. I ended up using the httptrigger template.

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Sensor
metadata:
  name: tibco-events-sensor
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        sidecar.istio.io/inject: 'false'
    serviceAccountName: operate-workflow-sa
  dependencies:
    - name: tibco-dep
      eventSourceName: tibco-events-source
      eventName: whatever
  triggers:
    - template:
        name: http-trigger
        http:
          url: http://argo-workflows.argo-workflows:2746/api/v1/workflows/lab-uat/submit
          secureHeaders:
            - name: Authorization
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: argo-workflows-sa-token
                  key: bearer-token
          payload: 
            - src:
                dependencyName: tibco-dep
                value: CronWorkflow
              dest: resourceKind
            - src:
                dependencyName: tibco-dep
                value: coinflip
              dest: resourceName
            - src:
                dependencyName: tibco-dep
                value: coinflip-event-
              dest: submitOptions.generateName
          method: POST
      retryStrategy:
        steps: 3
        duration: 3s
      policy:
        status:
          allow:
            - 200
```